# How can I call a function from another function in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to call a function from another function by onClick event to dispatch a state in Redux.
I can call the Jammingmenu when I click on Icon but there is no any action or show alert.
It would be grateful to help me.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import RestAPIContext from "ContextAPI/ContextAPI";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import StatusCard from "views/components/Components/StatusCard";
import {JammingMenu} from "./JammingMenu";

const Columns = [
    {
        field: 'action',
        headerName: 'Action',
        renderCell: sensorSelectedInfo => (actionColumn(sensorSelectedInfo)),
        headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header',
        width: 200
    }
];



// create custom cell for deleting, editing and activation of sensors
const actionColumn = sensorSelectedInfo =>
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
        <div className="flex-column"
            onClick={() => showDeletingHandler()}>  ///////////// HERE IS CLICK 
            <RiRadarFill size={25} />
        </div >
    </div >;


const showDeletingHandler = () =>
{
JammingMenu();//////////////////////  CALL THE FUNCTION TO CHANGE STATE IN REDUX
}


const Overview = ({ subTabSelected, subTabSelectedFromNewWin }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    let finalSubTabSelected = subTabSelected || subTabSelectedFromNewWin;

    const sensorLogEventHandler = sensorLogs => {

        // add human readable time to each log of sensor and throw out unnecessary data
        logsArr = sensorLogs.result.map(i => {

            // create headers list
            if (!headersImplemented) {
                headers = Object.keys(i);

                headers = [...headers, "humanDate", "humanTime"]
                    .map(x => {
                        return { label: x, selector: x };
                    });

                setLogsHeaders(headers);
                headersImplemented = true; // to prevent re-implement repeated headers
            }

            return {
                ...i,
                humanDate: moment(i.UTCTime).format("YY / MM / DD"),
                humanTime: moment(i.UTCTime).format("HH : mm : ss")
            }
        }
        );


    return <div className="h-100">
        {finalSubTabSelected === "allOverview" || !finalSubTabSelected ?
            <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%', backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }} className={classes.root}>

                <DataGrid rows={editable} columns={Columns} components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}

                    pageSize={100} hideFooter hideFooterPagination density="compact" showCellRightBorder backgroundColor='red'
                    getRowClassName={(params) =>
                        `super-app-theme--${params.getValue(params.id, 'sensorname')}`
                    }
                />
            </div>
        }
        <StatusCard />
    </div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        subTabSelected: state.MainControllerReducer.subTabSelected
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Overview);
```

Jammingmenu.js

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { SHOW_JAMMING_MENU } from "Redux/ActionTypes/MainControllerTypes";


export let JammingMenu = ({dispatch, showjamming}) => {
    alert("This is Function")
    dispatch({type: SHOW_JAMMING_MENU, showjamming: true});
return true

};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        showjamming: state.MainControllerReducer.showjammingmenu
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(JammingMenu);
```

How can I call a function from another function to trigger a dispatch of Redux to change state?

Comment: Your `Jammingmenu` is a React Component, not a function, so you can't invoke it like that

Comment: So how can I invoke it?

Comment: It's a small function, I'd suggest moving your `Jammingmenu` to your `Columns` component.

Comment: You also can't just return JSX from event callbacks and expect them to be rendered with everything else in the return of the component. What are you really wanting, or trying, to do here?

Answer (score 0):

In the `showDeletingHandler` function, you're not passing any of the `dispatch` or `show` parameters.

Your function should have something like:

```js
const showDeletingHandler = () => {
   JammingMenu({dispatch: //dispatch function,
                showJamming: //showJamming value 
});
}
```

Comment: OP has very likely mixed up named and default export... they very likely are thinking they are calling the default export that has the props injected. This is moot though since you can't directly invoke React functions in this way.